# Excel Populate Data

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following input data:

[image]

I need to populate each entry into 3 rows with different payout rates & periods, something like this:

[image]

Thecommission payout is based on the following rates:
i) 1st month - 50%
ii) 2nd month - 30%
iii) 3rd month - 20%

Example:-

[image]

The next criteria is the commission payout period. The current month collection will be paid in the following months.

How can I do it using a Excel & macro?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is on the 1st sheet, create a second sheet and run this macro:

```
Option Explicit

Sub popData()

 Dim r As Integer, r2 As Integer, p As Integer: r2 = 3
 Dim sht2 As Worksheet: Set sht2 = Sheets(2)

 Dim rate(), headings()
 rate = Array(0.5, 0.3, 0.2)
 headings = Array("Date", "Sales", "Commission", "Collection Date", "Invoice No")

 For r = 0 To UBound(headings):
   sht2.Cells(2, r + 1).Value = headings(r)
 Next

 Dim dat As Date
 With Sheets(1)
   sht2.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Payout"
   For r = 3 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row:
     For p = 0 To 2:
       sht2.Cells(r2, "A").NumberFormat = .Cells(r, "A").NumberFormat
       dat = DateAdd("m", p + 1, CDate(.Cells(r, "A")))
       sht2.Cells(r2, "A").Value = DateSerial(year(dat), month(dat) + 1, 0)
       sht2.Cells(r2, "B").Value = .Cells(r, "B").Value
       sht2.Cells(r2, "C").NumberFormat = "0.00"
       sht2.Cells(r2, "C").Value = .Cells(r, "C").Value * rate(p)
       sht2.Cells(r2, "D").NumberFormat = .Cells(r, "A").NumberFormat
       sht2.Cells(r2, "D").Value = .Cells(r, "A").Value
       sht2.Cells(r2, "E").Value = .Cells(r, "D").Value
       r2 = r2 + 1
     Next
   Next
 End With

 sht2.Columns("A:E").EntireColumn.AutoFit

End Sub
```

The first loop adds the headers to the 2nd sheet.  The next double loop processes each salesperson with the inner loop creating the 3 rows for each commission payout.  It appears that you want the last day of the next month - which is provided for by adding a month to the present date and then using the DateSerial function to find the last day of that month.  The last line just ensures all the columns are expanded to their largest text entry so everything is visible.